# Why this loop freezes my browser?

Tags: javascript, integer-overflow

Why browser hangs executing this?

```js
for(var i= 9007199254740993;i<9007199254740994;i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Because why someone wants overflow?

Comment: Because those integers and ridiculously huge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integers you are trying to use are larger than 2^53. JavaScript cannot represent those integers precisely. Lets have a look at the console:

```
> var i = 9007199254740993;
undefined
> i++
9007199254740992
> i++
9007199254740992
> i++
9007199254740992
...
```

As you can see, due to loss of precision, the value of `i` doesn't change, thus the condition will always be `true`, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: You beat me to it. Nice answer.

Comment: Ok. I sould have started with 9007199254740991 :)

Comment: @Ruslanas: No, you have to **end** at `9007199254740991`.